# Dual Boot after unique installations [Ubuntu 18.04.2 and Windows 7]

Tags: dual-boot

I have already an installation of Windows 7 on a [now removed] SSD disk.
I have installed on a new SSD disk Ubuntu 18.04.2.
How can i connect the first drive [with the previous Windows 7 installation] and have a functioning dual boot menu for both OS?
Motherboard is Asus P5B [not UEFI boot]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. If you think my answer is correct the please put the green check mark (✅) on the left margin of the answer. This will help others find the right answer with the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For those who will try this answer with newer computers**, make sure both Windows and Ubuntu are installed in either UEFI mode or both in Legacy BIOS mode. If Windows boots in UEFI mode (the default for computers with pre-installed WIndows) and Ubuntu boots in Legacy BIOS mode (or vice versa) then you won't be able to switch between the two OSes without going into UEFI setup and switching the boot mode every time.

## Reconnect the SSD containing Windows to the computer

## BIOS(or UEFI for newer computers) setup

Get into BIOS setup when the computer boots by pressing the BIOS setup key.

Make the the SSD with Ubuntu the first disk to boot from.

Save the changes and continue booting.

## After Booting Ubuntu

On first boot, you may or may not see the GRUB menu. If this happens you will directly boot Ubuntu. This is normal. After Ubuntu boots login using the username and password you selected during Ubuntu installation.

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> together. Then enter:

`sudo update-grub`<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>

You will be prompted for your password. When you enter the password in the terminal the cursor will not move, there will be no dots or ****. this is normal. Press <kbd>Enter↵</kbd> after password.

The above command will look through all the drives and discover that you have Windows 7 (and possibly recovery partitions) in Disk 1 and add these to the GRUB menu in Disk 2. It will not change anything in Disk 1.

In the next reboot, you will see the GRUB menu, something like:

[image]

Yours will look slightly different. If you do nothing after a few seconds the computer will boot Ubuntu.

- You can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to boot Ubuntu right away.
- To boot Windows, use the down arrow key <kbd>↓</kbd> to select Windows
  7 and press <kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

Hope this helps